# When writing an add in for Word 2016 in Javascript- how are changes to text detected?

Tags: javascript, ms-word, add-in

The events/listeners mechanism for Office add-ins [is quite baroque](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins), and examples are thin on the ground. How do you listen for user input in a Word add-in so that the text that the user types in can be analysed and acted upon in the add-in?

Comment: Did you find anything?